# Filamentphp - Builder

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-filament

i have a problem with Builder https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#builder it don't save data in json columns.

I have a model Post:

```
protected $casts = [
        'audio' => 'json',
        'audio_title' => 'json',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'audio_title',
        'audio',
    ];
```

My migration

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->json('audio_title')->nullable();
            $table->json('audio')->nullable();
        });
```

Builder code

```
\Filament\Forms\Components\Builder::make('Content')
     ->blocks([
\Filament\Forms\Components\Builder\Block::make('Audio')
                            ->schema([
                                TextInput::make('audio_title'),
                                FileUpload::make('audio')
                                ->directory('audio'),
                            ]),
                        ]),
```

When i save without Builder, it work

```
TextInput::make('audio_title'),
FileUpload::make('audio')
>directory('audio'),
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for help!

UPD.

the filament don't encoding data in json automatically. You should to get data in method, and encode their.
If you create record, use mutateFormDataBeforeCreate in
Filament->resource->NameResource->Pages->CreateName.php

```
protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
{

    $data['content'] = json_encode($data['block']);
    
    return $data;
}
```

If you edit record
Filament->resource->NameResource->Pages->EditName.php

```
protected function mutateFormDataBeforeSave(array $data): array
{
    $data['content'] = json_encode($data['block']);
    return $data;
}

protected function mutateFormDataBeforeFill(array $data): array
{

    $data['block'] = json_decode($data['content'], true);
    return $data;
}
```